# how can I call the java method instead of the new member functions if they have the same name

Tags: java, coldfusion, overloading, railo

Sadly it's not simply overloaded...

I'm trying to upgrade my application from railo 3.3 to 4.1

I'm using the underlying java methods quite often and most of the time this is not a problem. I have an array that I'm sorting using a java Comparator object:

```
a.sort(
    createObject(
        "java", 
        "AlphanumComparator", 
        "/model/java/AlphanumComparator.jar"
    )
);
```

Which runs fine on 3.3. But with the new member functions in 4.0 a new `array.sort` method is added which runs the same as `arraySort()`.

Now I get the following error:

```
invalid sort type [AlphanumComparator@someid], sort types are [text, textNoCase, numeric]
```

dumping the `getClass()` shows the original java method is still there but I cannot seem to call it...

Comment: Try getting a Java array with `a.toArray()` then call `.sort(Comparator)` on that?

Comment: than it cant find the sort method at all `No matching Method/Function for [Ljava.lang.Object;.sort(AlphanumComparator) found`

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking this was an internal Java method you were after, but it's not. Best way to get this solved is probably to ask on the [Railo mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/railo).

Comment: BTW, I dumped `getClass()` on a CFML array and the signature seems to be `void sort(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)` which is the member version of `arraySort()`, not the `Comparator` version you used to be able to call in Railo 3.3. See my answer below for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the `.sort()` method you were calling in 3.3 was "merely" an implementation detail of Railo's `railo.runtime.type.ArrayImpl` class, rather than a generic (standard) Java class. So that put you at risk that the implementation might change anyway - and it has.

A small code change will allow you to use `java.util.Collections` and the static `sort()` method there:

```
var Collections = createObject( "java", "java.util.Collections" );
Collections.sort( a, createObject( "java",
                                   "AlphanumComparator",
                                   "/model/java/AlphanumComparator.jar" ) );
```

I tested this on Railo 4.0.4.001 using a CFML array of strings and the default `java.text.Collator` so I believe it will work with your `java.util.Comparator` implementation too.